# Strange issue with unwanted small-caps in Firefox

Tags: html, css, firefox

Ok off the bat I appreciate this is a weird one but just throwing it out there as I'm out of clues.

Almost got sign off from a client when they brought it to my attention the navigation on the site was messing up when resizing in the browser.

It only occurred to me after they sent me a screen shot what was happening, take a look:

My browser (Firefox v29)

[image: screenshot one]

His browser (Firefox v29)
[image: screenshot two]

For some reason he is seeing something rendering with font-varient:small-caps; which is not even set in my css. I've even tried setting font-varient: normal; just in case.

Has anyone else come across this? It's really bugging me out because I can't possibly recreate the problem in order to fix it.

Thanks

Comment: did you tried clearing cache ? at both ends

Comment: Yeah.. Only thing I can think of is clearing the cache.

Comment: If you cannot recreate the problem, how could we? We have much less information – we have no access to the HTML and CSS involved, and we cannot contact your client. We cannot test whether other pages have the same problem in the client’s browser or whether that browser has a user style sheet installed.

Answer (score 1):

Ask your client to clear the browser's cache and history and reload the page with `Ctrl + R` key combination.

It seems to be an CSS style cache problem, the rule for the font in his case is 
`text-transform:capitalize` and in your case is `font-variant:normal`.

Also make sure that your client do not use *custom CSS style* in Firefox, which overrides the page's one. Some browser plug-ins allow such custom CSS style overwrite, for better accessibility.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, some good advice. Just to be double sure I've now specified text-transform:capitalize and font-variant:normal and Firebug confirms that this is being read. However I've asked a few other people to check it out and they are getting the same results as my client. That makes me think it's something specific to my machine. I've cleared the cache in all browsers but getting the same. This is weird!

Comment: Try to open the page with different browser, this CSS rule is not Firefox specific, so if it is related to your computer - then on all browsers you should see the same result, if not - that means that indeed it is caching problem

Answer (score 0):

Maybe it's related to default browser settings - he might [change it manually in Firefox settings](http://www-archive.mozilla.org/unix/customizing.html#usercss) or maybe some accessibillity software did it.